# Why multiplying two big numbers showing wrong answer?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   std::cout<<1000000000000000*56687463565256476;
   return 0;
}
```

Output of above program showing wrong answer.How can I get the correct answer ?

Comment: By getting informed about integer (unsigned integer) mathematics (ranges and overflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operands of the multiplication are integral types. As you haven't supplied a suffix on the operands, your compiler will attempt to coerce them into an `int`, and if that fails, a `long int`. With C++11 it will additionally attempt a coercion to a `long long int`. So pre-C++11 your program behaviour could be undefined at this point, but with C++11 both operands can be represented as a `long long int` as that *must* be at least 64 bits.

So the problem is either down to that or the fact that your system doesn't have an integral type large enough to represent that product (which is probably evaluated at compile time). So your program behaviour is undefined.

If you promote one of the arguments to floating point, then the output will be in floating point, albeit with the associated loss of precision (usually about 15 significant figures).

Take a look at `std::numeric_limits` for more details.

Comment: Nitpick: afaik your compiler can provide an integral type large enough to represent the product, but still give the "wrong" product if the literals are interpreted as being of a 64-bit type.

Comment: Why wrong answer? There is a possibility of getting a 64 bit number even after multiplication..